# Mains powered NMOS 100KHz switch with push-pull MOSFET driver

Tags: mains, mosfet-driver, linear-regulator

I'm trying to design a mains powered switched resistive load to inject high frequency (100KHz) noise current into mains wiring to facilitate magnetic tracing of in wall wires (I know about the electric-field based tracing).
See the schematic below.

I'm planning to use a CMOS 555-timer to drive a NMOS switch using a power resistor (R4) as the load  (31K for 10mA peak current).

To keep things simple I'm trying to power the 555 IC with a simple 300K resistor + 5.6V zener regulator.
The 1mA current the supply is capable of is not enough to switch the MOSFET (M1) fast enough so I've added a 2uF cap (C4) to provide the peak current needed.

Now the 555-timer also has limited sink and source currents so I thought about using a PMOS/NMOS pair as a push-pull driver (M2/M3) for the main MOSFET M1.

But my simulation is showing that with this arrangement both M2 and M3 are ON at the same time for most of their on time and this results into conduction from VCC trough M2 and M3 to ground. This way the zener is not getting any current and the supply voltage stays low at 2.4V and the voltage on M2's and M3's gates (OUT of the timer) stays between Vcc and Ground because there's not enough current left to charge the gates' capacitance in 1 cycle. This keeps both M2 and M3 partially ON at the same time and we've got a stable state that it's stuck in.

If I somehow could prevent the timer from starting until C4 is charged to the supply's target voltage of 5.6V then the charged capacitor could provide enough peak current to switch M2 and M3 in one cycle, but I'm not sure what's the easiest way of achieving this.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Edit:** The simulation gives the expected results when I drive M1 directly from the OUT pin, but the real timer won't have enough source/sink current as I mentioned above.

[LTSpice model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lsqszNaCBPmBDpEMydUA16uHLFxKeTQX/view?usp=sharing).

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 1):

IRF701 requires 10V gate drive, so you'll need a 10-12V power supply. You can use any old 12V wall wart for this.

With a supply capable of a bit more current than a capacitor dropper you can use a NE555 which should have enough output current to drive the FET. Or you could use a MOSFET driver like MCP1401, but the input takes only 5V.

Comment: thanks! 5.6V appears to be enough considering I'm driving a 31KOhm load with it, at least in the simulation. Now I'm thinking maybe some sort a of a logic buffer for M3 and an inverter for M2 would do the trick of always keeping only one of the MOSFETs open.

Comment: MCP1401 costs 50 cents ;)

Comment: thanks! will need to look if I can find it from a local supplier, that's another limation I didn't mention, ordering from Aliexpress takes a month or 2 to deliver.

Comment: Ah well, you should be able to find a NE555 and a 12V power supply, honestly this 2 MOSFET schematic always has cross conduction problems